# Usage of Proxy with with

Tags: javascript

What this code is doing?

As I see, it uses `Proxy` with `with`.

```js
try {
    let self = this
    window.bareWords = new Proxy({}, {
        has: function(target, name) {
            return !(name in self)
        },
        get: function(target, name) {
            return name
        },
    })
} catch(e) {
    console.error('Your browser doesn\'t support bare words.')
}

with(bareWords) {
    alert(Banana + Hell)
    console.log(We, can, use, bare, words)
}
```

Comment: Be nice to know some more context here.

Comment: The `with` part just makes it roughly equivalent to `console.log(bareWords.We, bareWords.can, bareWords.use, bareWords.bare, bareWords.words)`.

Comment: @garrett-motzner I don't know the context so much. I just found strange code. I am not so profound in JS, so I decided to ask the question.

Comment: What exactly do you find unclear? Have you read the documentation? [`Proxy`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), [`with`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). Have you read the [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-with-statement)?

Comment: And this is exactly the reason why the `with` statement has been deprecated.

Comment: @Bergi, yeah, I can see why that bugs people, but I'm not sure that's a justification entirely. Really, I like when languages let you abuse them, because then you can do powerful things. Distrust of users doing overly clever things doesn't seem like the best reason to restrict features. (But making things impossible to optimize is a good reason, and so is not wanting to support extreme edge cases). In this case, `with` lets you do a lot of things ruby lets you do as well. And sometimes it's nice to do that, even if you wouldn't often want to.

Comment: Concerning the clarity of this question, stack overflow does expect people to make an effort to answer their own question, and show your work. (It makes us feel respected, and not like proxies for google ;) ) So, since you didn't show that you had tried to figure it out, the question got downvoted and closed. I don't think it's a bad question though, it just needs better presentation. So maybe show where you found it, why you were interested, and explain exactly what you understand and don't about the question.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is doing some tricky Metaprogramming, to allow some unconventional behavior in some cases. Essential, it's a clever trick that lets you, within the context of the `with` block, use any js identifier as a string.

You wouldn't use this often in js, as it creates surprising behavior. And, if you are using strict mode (which is enabled by default in classes and modules) `with` is disabled (which I find disappointing, but understandable).

But here's what the two parts are doing: Proxies let you create an object that lets you dynamically respond to calls for undefined properties. In this case, we return the name of the property called for any property, and we pretend that any property does in fact exist.

The `with` block then checks against the proxy for every identifier. If the identifier is defined on the with block (which the proxy always says it is) then it looks up the value from the proxy.